# Qgis 2.8 problem with font size

Tags: qgis, print-composer, font

I'm using Debian 7 and yesterday i had an update of Qgis 2.8. Since then I can't change font size and type, at labeling and print composer, whatever i pick it returns to the default  "Free sans" size 11. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is a known issue in 2.8. It is fixed and will be in the 2.8.1 release very soon.